# Get string from specific text Document, C#

Tags: c#, io

In my `Folder` I have one *Console application* and one *Text Document*:

```
Folder                  
  Console application.exe <- I execute this
  Text Document.txt       <- I want to read this
```

I want to read the *Text Document* with a help of `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)`, but my problem is that I have to specify the `path` which can *vary* from computer to computer since the *Console application* can be installed into *different* `Folder`s. How can can I obtain the right `path`?

Comment: You could locate the document relative to your working-directory, which is where your application compiles to.

Comment: keep the path that will work on all computers :) . if it's in your project then access it accordingly. with   methods like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx you can make it generic.

Comment: @Mandar Jogalekar: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` is the executing *assembly*, not *exe*; if the console application consists of *many* assemblies (say, a tiny exe and libraries) it can well appear that 
`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` return something like `c:\Windows\assembly\MyLib.dll` which is incorrect in the context: `c:\Windows\assembly\Text Document.txt`. `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the text file which is in the *same folder* the exe is:

```
  string path = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]), // exe folder
   "myTextDocument.txt"); //TODO: Put the right file name here

  string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Here we exploit the fact that the very 1st command line argument - `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` is a full name of the exe.